# Semantic UI React href of label in corner of image with its own href causes errors

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am receiving "Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of ." error when trying to get a label with a href to appear in the corner of an image which also has a href. I understand that this is because of nested  tags, but I cannot get any other way to work when i try different "as" properties. Either the image link doesn't work, or the label link doesn't work.

Current code:

```
<Image
  href="some-link"
  as="a"
  fluid
  src="https://somesource.com"
  label={{
    corner: "right",
    icon: "plus",
    as: "a",
    href: "#",
    onClick: () => {
      dosomestuff();
    },
  }}
/>
```

I want clicking the image to link to the images href, and clicking the label to run a js function as defined in the code.

Appreciate any help

Here is a code sandbox demonstrating what I am trying to achieve. Notice how the only way to get the label to link differently to the image is using two a tags.

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wildflower-cnvzp?file=/example.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have achieved the desired result. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, and if there may be performance/accessibility issues.

When any part of the image is clicked the nodeName of the element determines the result. If it is "IMG" then the image was clicked. Otherwise, the "a" or icon was clicked.

```
<Image
  fluid
  src="https://somesource.com"
  onClick={(el) => {
    if (el.target.nodeName === "IMG") {
      history.push(`product/${product.slug}`);
    } else {
      addProduct(product._id, product.title);
    }
  }}
  label={{
    corner: "right",
    icon: "plus",
    as: "a",
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a serious Accessibility concern. Don't put any *anchor tag* inside a label.

> Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label. Doing so makes it difficult for people to activate the form input associated with the label. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Instead, put the anchor tag in different tag like `<p>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if I don't put an anchor inside a label then clicking it just links to the url of the image. I have added a code sandbox to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I split it into 3 components and it works for me.

```
   <Card key={file.id}
      style={{border: '3px solid red', padding: 2}}>
    <Image
        ///////////////////////////
        // label={{
        //     as: 'a',
        //     corner: 'right',
        //     icon: 'delete',
        //     color: 'red',
        // }}
        //////////////////////////
        src={'http://localhost:8000/api/storage/downloadFile?fileName=' + file.fileName}
        wrapped
        alt={file.id}
        onClick={this.handleOnClickOnImage}
        ui={false}
    />
    <Label
        onClick={this.handleOnClickCornerDeleteImage}
        value={file.id}
        as='a'
        corner='right'
        icon='delete'>
        <Icon value={file.id} name='delete'/>
    </Label>
</Card>
```